# AWS DMS task has been deleted, how to recover those deleted dms task created for data load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, data-migration, aws-dms, dms

Accidently deleted the completed DMS task, need to recover those to perform it again once the tables are truncated in the database**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

I have been using DMS for a while now. I don't believe there is a way to recover a deleted dms task. I did have a look at the AWS documentation and was not able to find anything about recovering a deleted task.
The official guide/documentation can be found at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html

regards,
Naveed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).